# what exactly rebuildhttpdconf script do?

Tags: httpd

Recently I found there is lots of warnings in my VPS's httpd.conf

There is a solution in [this forum](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/httpd-restart-188951.html) about rebuilding httpd.conf:

```
# cd /usr/local/apache/conf
# cp -p httpd.conf httpd.conf.old-bak
# /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf
# /scripts/restartsrv_httpd
# /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl status
```

but I fear it delete current domains configurations. what exactly this script do with my server?

Comment: If you post the contents of that script, we'll be able to tell you *exactly* what it does.

Comment: It is one of cpanel's scripts, is it really to post its content here?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what their terms of service are, you're their customer not me. But I'd guess that since they made it a shell script and not a binary, they're probably not trying to guard it too closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will simply take information from the database and create the httpd.conf from known good values. It won't revert domains hosted in CPanel, but if you have made custom changes to httpd.conf, those will be reverted.

The command is generally used when a sysadmin has broke httpd.conf by making manual edits.